# How could this spring webflow action state executed?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I saw a spring web flow like this. As you could see, there are two view states and both of them will be called by links outside this flow. But I have no idea why each time this flow is activated, the action state will always be called. I personally think there should be an on-entry tag. Any thoughts? I appreciate your help.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow.xsd">

        <action-state id="start">
            <evaluate expression="aaa.fsdf()"/>
            <evaluate expression="aaa.bbb()"/>
            <transition on="yes" to="viewone"/>
            <transition on="no" to="viewtwo"/>
        </action-state>

        <view-state id="viewone" view="web/ccc">
        </view-state>

        <view-state id="viewtwo" view="web/eee">
        </view-state>


        <end-state id="final" view="web/final">
        </end-state>

    </flow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how flows work in Spring Webflow. see [documentation about flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/defining-flows.html#flow-element)

> The first state defined becomes the flow's starting point.

Also, you cannot directly call a state within a flow directly. Let's say your flow is name "test-flow", in a file called test-flow.xml

when you call the flow via URL, using `yoursite.com/test-flow` it will enter the flow and the first state of the flow. so if you want to call a specific view state within the flow, you have to use some logic to direct the flow into the state you want. 
One way to do this is to pass a parameter, like `yoursite.com/test-flow?test=1` and in your flow, use an action state to check for that parameter and transition to the proper view-state.

This is what is happening here, the action state in your flow is the starting point, and based on some logic it will transition to your `viewone` or `viewtwo`.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is really clear and helpful!